# Risk in adding shared mail server to my SPF like sendinblue/sendgrid for mail reputation?

Tags: email, spam, spf

My enterprise would like to make some mass mailing to their customers, using a third party solution (e.g.: sendinblue, sendgrid, mailchimp...).

Is there a real risk that my domain mail address could be considered as spam if the shared IP is badly used by one of the shared service's evil customers (e.g., for spamming, even just for a week)?

In the worst case, would every mail sent under this enterprise domain name be considered by the security solutions as some spam (iron point, proofpoint...) and blocked?

In such scenario, how long it could take to be back a good mail reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP that the email service uses would be blacklisted, not the domain. This affects the service more than your company, which is why they tend to have very strict controls and procedures.

It does mean, though, that if you depend on that service, then you will be impacted by your emails not getting out if sent through that service.